# Same css style in the same page, result is different (Android browser)

Tags: html, css, android-browser

The problem is shown in the picture below, the avatar of each item in the waterfall flow uses the same css style, but sometimes an avatar does not in center (like the last item). Only Android Browser has this problem, IOS is fine.

[image]

The HTML and CSS is as follows:

```
<div class="m-headimg-wrapper ">
    <img class="m-headimg-img" src="xxxx">
</div>

.m-headimg-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 0.28rem;
    height: 0.28rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 0.1rem;
    border-radius: 0.28rem;
    overflow: hidden;

    &:after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 0.56rem;
        height: 0.56rem;
        transform: scale(0.5) translate(-50%, -50%);
        border: 1px solid #00bcd4;
        border-radius: 0.56rem;
    }

    .m-headimg-img {
        width: 0.26rem;
        height: 0.26rem;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 0.26rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem has been solved, because the px converted from rem is a decimal number. Using px directly will not cause this problem, but it's still curious why only part of the items have problems with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, because the px converted from rem is a decimal number. Using px directly will not cause this problem, but it's still curious why only part of the items have problems with decimals.